# Oracle: Date format

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to concat a date and a time which are `VARCHAR2` and then pass it to a `DATE`. The problem is that when I pass it to `DATE` it does not print the date time ont the `date`format`. What am I doing wrong?

```
  o_data_final DATE;
  i_data       VARCHAR2:= '12/06/2000';
  i_hora       VARCHAR2:= '12:23:00';

  dbms_output.put_line('print:'||concat(concat(i_data,' '),i_hora));
  --prints correctly: 12/06/2000 12:23:00

  SELECT to_date(concat(concat(i_data,' '),i_hora), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  INTO o_data_final
  FROM dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('data:'||to_char(o_data_final));
  --prints wrong: 00.06.12
```

I want that o_data_final be 12/06/2000 12:23:00. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need to pass the format into TO_CHAR function like:

```
dbms_output.put_line('data:'||to_char(o_data_final, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'));
```

Oracle stores date in internal binary format and it has no specific human-readable format. You will need to use format in `TO_CHAR` or set the default format for the session using `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss';
```

Currently, you are getting the output: `00.06.12` as currently your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `yy.mm.dd`

You can fetch the current session value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` using the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE
    PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

try please:

```
  declare 
  o_data_final DATE;
  i_data       VARCHAR2(2000):= '12/06/2000';
  i_hora       VARCHAR2(2000):= '12:23:00';
  begin
  dbms_output.put_line('print:'||concat(concat(i_data,' '),i_hora));
  --prints correctly: 12/06/2000 12:23:00

  SELECT to_date(i_data||' '||i_hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  INTO o_data_final
  FROM dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('data:'||to_char(o_data_final, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
  end;
```

or

```
  declare 
  o_data_final DATE;
  i_data       VARCHAR2(2000):= '12/06/2000';
  i_hora       VARCHAR2(2000):= '12:23:00';
   begin
  dbms_output.put_line('print:'||concat(concat(i_data,' '),i_hora));
  --prints correctly: 12/06/2000 12:23:00

  SELECT to_date(concat(concat(i_data,' '),i_hora), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  INTO o_data_final
  FROM dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('data:'||to_char(o_data_final, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
  end;
```